# When should we include the "Replicate" in an ANOVA table for Factorial Design?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

*I already [asked on stat.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376085/when-should-we-include-the-replicate-in-an-anova-table-for-factorial-design), but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask here as well.*

*The tags may not be the best options but on here they are the closest to an ANOVA tag I could find*

When I have been learning how to do Factorial Designs ($2^k$ mainly) the ANOVA table would usually include the main effects, all the interaction effects if necessary, and the error. However, on one of my exams it not only included the factors and their interactions, and the error, but it also included "replication".

First off, I was never taught that we could have replication as one of our sources of variation. So I don't know how that could effect the Sum of Squares of Error. I'm just guessing here, but I guess the degrees of freedom should be $n-1$ if we have $n$ replicates, but I am only guessing that because everything else appears to be of the form $\theta - 1$ for some parameter $\theta$.

Up to this point I have never included replication in my ANOVA table. Should replication be included and if it is included how does it affect the Sums of Squares?

The exact example we had was that we had a $3$ factor experiment with two replicates and it gave us part of the ANOVA table, and we had to fill in the rest. If it didn't include Replication, I would know exactly how to fill in the rest of the table, but I don't know exactly why Replication would need to be checked whether or not it is significant or not.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\text{Source of Variation} & \text{df} & \text{SS} & \text{MS} & \text{F-Value} & \text{p-value} \\ \hline
\text{Replication} &  & 300 \\ \hline
\text{A} &  & & 120\\ \hline
\text{B} &  & 320 \\ \hline
\text{C} &  &  & 60 \\ \hline
\text{AB} &  & &55 \\ \hline
\text{AC} &  &160  \\ \hline
\text{BC} &  &100  \\ \hline
\text{ABC} &  &  \\ \hline
\text{Error} &  &  \\ \hline
\text{Total} & & 2000\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We are given that each factor is three levels, two replicates, and that the treatment sum of squares is $1200$

If this table doesn't include the row "Replicates" I know how to fill in all the missing entries. But since it is there, I don't really know how to account for that correctly. Nor do I understand why we would ever want to have that included in our ANOVA

Any help on my confusion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, are you sure it 'replication' and not 'residual'. Often the Error line in an ANOVA is called Residual. // If it is Residual, can you give the model, say what software you're using, and show all the lines in the ANOVA table?

Comment: @BruceET I know it says "replication" as I have it in front of me; will edit question and add the table I am supposed to fill in